# Using collection_singular_ids=ids without saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In rails I'm using the `other_ids=[...]` method to assign connections on a `has_many :through` association.  It works fine, except when I don't want to commit the `other_ids=[...]` to the database (assigning with this method automatically saves).

Is there a way to assign these connections while just using Model.new?  An example of when this is useful is for when I submit a form that has checkboxes for a `has_many` relationship.  When the form doesn't save (when validation fails) the selected checkboxes get reset.

Model:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
  attr_accessible :category_ids
end
```

View:

```
select :category_ids, Category.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, {:multiple => true}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's odd. I mean, I understand why it saves, because it's a relation of other records and not the one you are working with it but should be simple to implement that feature in AR, I think.

Anyways, you can do something like the following to work around this. Using virtual attributes

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :save_foos
  has_many :foos

  attr_accessor :temp_foo_ids # Bad name for it but whatever...
  attr_accessible :temp_foo_ids

  def save_foos
    foo_ids = temp_foo_ids  # it should save the record like this again right?
  end
end
```

In the view you would also use the virtual attribute

```
select :temp_foo_ids, Foo.all.collect {|x| [x.name, x.id]}, {}, {:multiple => true}
```

I haven't tested anything of this but I'm confident it will work ;)